# Chrome 45: Images with inline CSS {position:relative;} not displaying

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Can someone help me here I am using latest Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 and encountered issue that images with CSS {position:relative} are not displaying properly.

I have reported this in Chromium as well https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528143&thanks=528143&ts=1441346914 here is the link for that. Any help will be appreciated

Its working fine in all other browsers but not working only in Chrome tried 32bit and 64bit both. It was working fine in old version as I have one in my second Laptop

Comment: Works fine for me. You need to post a demo to give this some context.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528143&thanks=528143&ts=1441346914 check this out

Comment: That's an image that doesn't tell us much. You should be able to set up a demo, on CodePen or whatever, that demonstrates the issue. It may be something in your CSS that's causing the problem.

Comment: codepen.io is not a browser I cannot identify Chrome issue is codepen, please https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528143 check some one else is also reporting the same issue

Comment: A CodePen demo runs in the browser, so the problem will show up in Chrome.

Comment: try to update ur browser. A new version was released 45.0.2454.93 m. Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Please give us some code so we have at least some hope of replicating the problem. Be more specific than "not displaying properly". What are you expecting vs what is actually happening.

Comment: http://codepen.io/sedovsek/pen/XmmzYY please check this, it is not working only in chrome and working fine in all other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Issue still not fixed I just checked on Version 45.0.2454.93 m (64-bit) :(

But following CSS code can fix it. Images are not visible only when they are under anchor tag so adding following code in anchor tag can fix it.

`a {display: inline-block}`